# When I try to play a sever it says “invalid identity public key” and doesn’t let me join

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

It always says Invalid identity public key And then I think maybe it is just for today and then the next day I went to try it then it says the same thing and then I go on a week later and the same thing happens so I went to look up stuff to help me and there was nothing except this website.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. A screenshot of the error message and the screen where you input said key will help us answer your question better.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you at least tried restarting your game/console?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-writing the server adress. If that doesn't work, try updating minecraft. If it's a java-edition server you can't connect to it from bedrock-edition, so try instaling java.